# d3 typescript geopath this

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I have a geometric transformation function in my React typescript app that looks like below.

```
        // Use Leaflet to implement a D3 geometric transformation.
        const projectPoint = ( x: any, y: any) => {
          const point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
          this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
        }
```

**However I get an error "Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)" for `this`.**
So I looked at doing an If statement to check if it is undefined (see below) but that doesn't work

```
        const projectPoint = ( x: any, y: any) => {
          const point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
          if (this != undefined) {
           this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
          } else {
            return null
          }
        }
```

And even tried below..

```
        const projectPoint = ( x: any, y: any) => {
          const point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
           this!.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
        }
```

But i get the error that Property 'stream' does not exist on type 'never'. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is this not a an issue of using fat arrow notation which changes the `this` context as compared with using `function() {...` ?

Comment: Yes that's what I started with but that came the error "An outer value of 'this' is shadowed by this container." @AndrewReid

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was unrelated to "this" (pardon the pun).
Though I have incorrectly written this projectPoint function. The correct function should declare this with **this: any** as follows.

```
        // Use Leaflet to implement a D3 geometric transformation.
        const projectPoint = ( this:any, x: any, y: any) => {
          const point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
          this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
        }
```

What would be a better type than "any" for "this" that I could use out of interest?